# Barcode scanning in every direction using Zbar or Zxing

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, zbar

I would like to scan barcode (especially code128) in every direction. I integrated zbar and zxing libraries which scanned the code only horizontally or vertically but in other direction I couldn't. Is it possible to configure these libraries to scan barcodes in every direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No for zxing, although it scans back and forth. but you can simply rotate the image at will and retry. Given the dimensions of a barcode you only need about 10 rotations to cover all possibilities. This is 10 lines of code or so.

Comment: Ok. I will try to add rotation to support scanning diagonally.

Comment: Could you point the correct place where I should do this calculation?

Comment: Any solution for that?

Comment: Just rotate your image 45 degrees using APIs in BufferedImage, then try (also) scanning that.